nfs4_setfacl returns Failed operation: Invalid argument on EMC Isilon
I have configured the EMC simulator for NFSv4 ACLs by connecting to the AD.
The nfs4_getfacl command seems to be working for me-:
sudo nfs4_getfacl *
# file: dir00
A::OWNER@:rwaDxtTnNcCy
A::GROUP@:rxtncy
A::EVERYONE@:rxtncy

# file: new_dir
A::OWNER@:rwaDdxtTnNcCoy
A::GROUP@:rxtncy
A::EVERYONE@:rxtncy

but the setfacl command returns Failed operation: Invalid argument on EMC Isilon
What is the setting required to allow setfacl on the EMC Isilon Simulator

We're running into the same error when running nfs4_setfacl on shares from our Isilon. I've found a lot of information about similar returned errors, but only yours is the exact message that we're getting.
Have you confirmed that your Isilon and the NFSv4 client have the same domain string set (it may be case sensitive) in your /etc/idmapd.conf file? I have also tried to enable sss as one of the accepted Method's in the same configuration file, but it did not help in my case.
I noticed that your nfs4_getfacl output had no ACE values at all. Have you tried to define any on the Isilon itself yet and then ensure that you can retrieve that information on the client using nfs4_getfacl again? In my experience you should be able to query the existing ACE's set on the Isilon even if you're struggling to set new ones.
If you already found an alternative solution that wasn't related to the /etc/idmapd.conf file, please share your answer and mark it appropriately as well.
